# Proper way to declare two parameters in a Objective-C method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

This might be a ridiculous question but I can't find it asked yet here already.

Have a protocol delegate method defined:

```
- (void)myAddViewController:(MyAddViewController *)myAddViewController 
             loadGPS:(BOOL)gps loadCamera:(BOOL)camera;
```

which basically is to determine whether the GPS system is to be loaded or the camera should be loaded.

I call this method via:

```
[self.delegate myAddViewController:self loadGPS:YES loadCamera:NO];
// or alternatively
[self.delegate myAddViewController:self loadGPS:NO loadCamera:YES];
```

Inside my implemented method in the delegate we have:

```
- (void)myAddViewController:(MyAddViewController *)myAddViewController loadGPS:(BOOL)gps loadCamera:(BOOL)camera {
 .... .... ...  
if (gps) {
        ......
    }

    if (camera) {
      // camera is ALWAYS nil and never seems to be set?!
      .....

    }
```

So why when I call the delegate method with Camera: YES is the *camera* var always nil? It seems like it is never recognizing my second var yet it doesn't mind compiling? :)

Comment: I would try to avoid thinking of a BOOL as nil. True, that NO is a char set to 0, which is commonly equivalent to nil, but nil is meant to serve as a null pointer to an object.  A BOOL should be YES or NO, and in if statements, it is often more clear to use BOOL's like if ( camera == YES ) etc.  

Interesting problem though. Curious to see what the problem is.

Comment: Where is the code where you send the delegate the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a waste to pass in two mutually exclusive boolean values to a method.

Perhaps you'd be better with two delegate methods:

```
[self.delegate myAddGPSViewController:self];
// or alternatively
[self.delegate myAddCameraViewController:self];
```

because when you're firing the delegate methods, you'll already know whether you want GPS or Camera anyway.

Comment: yea. I'm going to be switching it up to this approach but I'd still like to know the answer to how to properly pass two vars to a method in obj-c.

Answer (score 0):

It might have, 
declaring 'camera' variable again,
can you paste your method

`- (void)myAddViewController:(MyAddViewController *)myAddViewController loadGPS:(BOOL)gps loadCamera:(BOOL)camera {`

\here?